# Pinterest Ajax Get Pins Invalid Label

Tags: ajax, json, api, get, pinterest

```
var url = "http://pinterestapi.co.uk/" + pinterestUsername + "/pins";

$.ajax({
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url,
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data)
    }
});
```

firebug "invalid character" error shows

dataType:"json" is not working

Answer (score 0):

<s>Try .getJSON().</s>

```
var url = "http://pinterestapi.co.uk/"+pinterestUsername+"/pins";

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    alert(data);
});
```

Ok, lets try something different...

Assuming you are the user "jwmoz".

```
   var user = "jwmoz";
   var url = "http://pinterestapi.co.uk/"+user+"/pins";

   $.get(url,
       function(data) {
       alert(data)
   }, "jsonp");
```

Check out this page [jQuery AJAX cross domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain), this should give you a rough idea and several userful links to solve your problem.

Ps- sorry for misunderstanding your question first time around! Best of luck!!

Dom

Comment: This will not work as I assume the OP is getting data from a different domain. .getJSON() uses a type of json not jsonp which is required for cross domain ajax calls.

Comment: "Wrong Character" error stops. But the "alert" not working.
http://prntscr.com/12436z
http://prntscr.com/1243in

Comment: Does not return JSON data.